# SQL select statement with increment

Tags: php, sql, select

Currently I'm using a for statement in PHP to get all the months for this SQL statement, but would like to know if I can do it all with SQL.

Basically I have to get the average listing price, and the average selling price for each month going back 1 year where the sellingdate = the month.

simple with PHP, but that creates 12 database hits.

I'm trying the sql statment below, but it returns listings totally out of order

```
SELECT 
avg(ListingPrice), 
avg(SellingPrice),
count(ListingDate),
DATE(SellingDate) as date,
MONTH(SellingDate) as month,
YEAR(SellingDate) as year
FROM `rets_property_resi` 
WHERE Area = '5030'
AND Status = 'S'
AND SellingDate "less then" = 'NOW()'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month desc
LIMIT 0,12
```

the "less then" is getting stripped from the statment, so please replace "less then" with the proper code

Output:

```
867507.142857   877632.492063   63  1996-12-24  12  1996
971355.833333   981533.333333   60  1997-11-18  11  1997
949334.328358   985453.731343   67  1997-10-23  10  1997
794150.000000   806642.857143   70  1996-09-20  9   1996
968371.621622   988074.702703   74  1997-08-21  8   1997
1033413.366337  1053018.534653  101 1997-07-30  7   1997
936115.054795   962787.671233   73  1996-06-07  6   1996
875378.735632   906921.839080   87  1996-05-16  5   1996
926635.616438   958561.643836   73  2010-04-13  4   2010
1030224.472222  1046332.291667  72  2010-03-31  3   2010
921711.458333   924177.083333   48  1997-02-28  2   1997
799484.615385   791551.282051   39  1997-01-15  1   1997
```

As you can see, it pulls from random dates, I need to to pull from 2010-03, 2010-02, 2010-01, etc...

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    avg(ListingPrice), 
    avg(SellingPrice),
    count(ListingDate),
    MONTH(SellingDate) as month,
    YEAR(SellingDate) as year
FROM `rets_property_resi` 
WHERE Area = '5030'
    AND Status = 'S'
    AND SellingDate <= NOW()
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year desc, month desc
LIMIT 0,12
```